# How to export a specific variable in javascript to node using module.export

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function called `startTime()` which contains a variable h that is set to the hour of the time function. I globaled h with `globalThis` and wanted to export it to my node side but after exporting it h becomes undefined. To debug if h is actually set to a value I created a new function called `exportVariable()` which contains an `alert(h)`. When I run `exportVariable()` from the client/html side it correctly alerts the current hour of the `startTime()` function so this means h is defined. What could possibly be causing h not to be defined after exporting it? My current code of both javascript and node side is attached below. The error location is on the javascript side.

JavaScript

```
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    globalThis.h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
  }
  function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
  }

var currentTime = h;

function exportVariable(){
    alert(h)
}



module.exports = {
    currentTime,
    
};
```

node

```
const isModule = require('./index.js');

const time = isModule.currentTime;
```

Error

```
var currentTime = h;
                  ^

ReferenceError: h is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous>
```

Comment: `h` wont be defined until you call `startTime` which you never do.

Comment: why do I need to call start time if h is set as a global variable?@Quentin

Comment: The code which sets it as a global variable is **inside `startTime`** so it won't run and set it as a global variable until you call that function!

Comment: Thanks that is probably what is causing the error. But how come h was defined when I called alert(h) without calling startTime().@Quentin

Comment: I've no idea what you did to define it in that test case, it doesn't work here: https://jsfiddle.net/5pxur2sc/

Comment: i edited your link. click on the time button to get alert(h). https://jsfiddle.net/rcLnt16z/ @Quentin

Comment: You call startTime before alerting h!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem that I see is that the functions are never called. `h` is defined inside `startTime()`, but this function isn't called before the assignment at `var currentTime = h`, so `h` is actually `undefined` there.

It should be:

```js
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    globalThis.h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
  }
  function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
  }
startTime() //ADDED ON SOLUTION
var currentTime = h;

function exportVariable(){
    alert(h)
}



module.exports = {
    currentTime,
    
};
```

Comment: That isn't really the *main* problem here, just the first problem. You are copying the **initial** value of the variable to `h` and then to `currentTime` and then exporting that value. Since `startTime` calls itself recursively presumably the desire is for that value to get updated (and this code won't do that).

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to keep on calling startTime so that the hour and minute can keep on updating in real-time? I have already tried setInterval(startTime, 500); but its not working. @Quentin